# Jquery Slidetoggle - Can't seem to get it to start off Closed?

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I am using a jquery slidetoggle on a single page website. I have been trying to figure out where I went wrong in my script but can't seem to resolve this issue. I am trying to get the slide toggle effect to start off closed when the page opens and open/close only on click. Right now, when the page opens each section of the slide toggle is already open :/ Any help would be appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
var openText = 'Open';
var closeText = 'Close';
$('.item-util .more-toggle').toggle(
    function() {
        $(this).html(closeText);
        $(this).parent().siblings('div').slideToggle('slow');
    },
    function() {
        $(this).html(openText);
        var returnTo = $(this).parents('.item');
        $.scrollTo(returnTo, {offset:{top:-150, left:0}, duration:600});
        $(this).parent().siblings('div').slideToggle('slow');
    }
  );
});
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Set the style of the elements you want to start closed as `display:none` and it should work...

Comment: great! problem solved. Thanks for the help. Not sure how or why I passed that up

Answer (score 2):

To have it start off as closed you need to set the css to `display: none;` for the element that you are trying to slide.

Comment: thanks for the help! problem solved by setting the display property to none